# Building filename from command outputs results in ambigous redirect error

Tags: bash, command-substitution

I want to edit a file and write it to anoter location without .template at the end. To do so, I use two commands in a row which should give me the new file name, but bash doesn't accept it. I heard you should do this with backquotes but I can't get it to work (the first sed is correct don't bother):

```
sed -E '/^\s*(#.*)?$/d; s/^\s*(\S+)\s+("([^"]*)"|(\S+)).*/s\/\1\/\3\4\/g/' "$file" > `$(basename $file) | sed -E 's/(.*).template$/.translated\1/g')`
```

I get such errors:

```
translate: command substitution: line 25: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
translate: command substitution: line 25: `$(basename $file) | sed -E 's/(.*).template$/.translated\1/g')'
translate: line 25: `$(basename $file) | sed -E 's/(.*).template$/.translated\1/g')`: ambiguous redirect
```

What should the redirect-to-filename part look like?

Comment: `>"$(basename "$file")"` is less ambiguous -- mind the quoting. Even then, though, it'll be ambiguous if `file` is empty.

Comment: However, what do you expect to happen when you use _both_ `>` _and_ `|` to redirect stdout of a single command? It can only go to one place -- a file _or_ a pipeline -- not both at once.

Comment: Consider `file_base=${file##*/}` as a prior command, and then using something more like `>"${file_base%.template}.translated"`. Even if it's not more correct, using built-in bash [parameter expansion](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) is orders-of-magnitude faster than starting a new copy of `sed` just to process a single line of input.

Comment: Re: "should do this with backquotes" -- backquotes are *never* better than `$(...)`, which has been the standardized way to do command substitution since the initial publication of POSIX.2 in 1991.

Comment: (If you really want your output file to be a hidden file whose name starts with `.translated`, then you might want `>".translated${file_base%.template}"`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Part 1: Why It Happens

Let's look at *why* you get a "ambiguous redirect" error.

When you run:

```
foo > `$(basename $file) | sed -E 's/(.*).template$/.translated\1/g')`
```

...that's telling the shell to first run a command:

```
$(basename $file) | sed -E 's/(.*).template$/.translated\1/g'
```

...and use its output as the redirection target.

However, `$(basename $file) | ...` is **not** the same as `basename $file | ...`! Let's say your file is named `/path/to/foo.template`. After that first command substitution happens, it's translated to:

```
foo.template | sed -E 's/(.*).template$/.translated\1/g'
```

...which is running *a command named* `foo.template` and feeding its output to `sed`.

Do you *have* a command named `foo.template`? If you don't, then that just generates an error on stderr, and nothing at all on stdout. Since stdout is what's fed into `sed`, that means `sed` receives no input at all, so it *writes* no output at all, so you have an empty filename.

And trying to redirect to an empty filename... is ambiguous! There's your bug.

---

## Part 2: Doing It Right

I'm assuming both your `sed` commands do what you want them to do (meaning that you *want* `foo.template` to create a file named `.footranslated` -- if you *don't* want to create this hidden file, your second `sed` operation is very wrong).

```
file_base=${file##*/}
sed -E '/^\s*(#.*)?$/d; s/^\s*(\S+)\s+("([^"]*)"|(\S+)).*/s\/\1\/\3\4\/g/' "$file" \
  >".translated${file_base%.template}"
```

...or, if your actual intent is to replace the extension `.template` with an extension `.translated`, that would instead be:

```
file_base=${file##*/}
sed -E '/^\s*(#.*)?$/d; s/^\s*(\S+)\s+("([^"]*)"|(\S+)).*/s\/\1\/\3\4\/g/' "$file" \
  >"${file_base%.template}.translated"
```

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate answer! I have trouble understanding this comment which I think is at the core of my misunderstanding:
>>However, what do you expect to happen when you use both > and | to redirect stdout of a single command? It can only go to one place -- a file or a pipeline -- not both at once. <<
What do you mean by that? I thought bash would use two pipelines and evaluate the right one to a filename which the left one can use but I think I'm wrong right?

Comment: What I meant by that: `foo > bar | baz` is telling `foo`'s output to go to `bar`, _and_ to go to the stdin of `baz`. However, each `write()` that `foo` does can only go to a single place; it can end up going to `bar`, or it can go to `baz`, but it can't do both (without something like `tee` that can do multiple `write()`s for each piece of data it `read()`s). That said, that initial comment is from before I noticed exactly where your backticks were (that's another reason to prefer `$(...)` -- it stands out more to readers).

Comment: Ahh interesting I will look into tee! However, what else would I have to do to evaluate that second statement bar | baz to a string which > can feed to as variable name? Is this possible?

Comment: `foo | tee bar | baz` will make `foo`'s output go both to the file named `bar` and the stdin of `baz`. But that's a different case than the one you actually care about here; afaict, what you're really looking for is `foo >"$(bar | baz)"`, which is simpler.